# Issue with the BACK button

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP programming infact its just been 3 days since I started so I need your help .
I am creating a form which contains 4 pages . When user clicks on Back button , for example from page 2 to page 1 all the data which he previously selected on page1 should be be present there so that he need not fill it again . 
Could you please help me with this by posting the code .

Here is the sample code

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$session=session_id();
$_SESSION['session']=$session;

    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">
    Where do you work?<br/>
    <Input type ="radio" name="location" value="USA" <?php if($_SESSION['location']    == 'USA') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>In the United states<br/>
    <Input type ="radio" name="location" value="India" <?php if($_SESSION['location'] == 'India') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>Outside of the United states<br/>

    <input name="Operation1" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
    <input name="Operation2" type="submit" value="next" />

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['session']==$session)
{
$location=$_SESSION['location'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
}
?>

<html>

<body>

<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">

In my work group, we are actively involved in making our work processes more effective and efficient (simpler, faster, etc.) using ACE.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

I have received the training I need to understand and implement ACE in my work group.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

All employees at the company are treated fairly regardless of differences.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

Sufficient effort is made to get the opinions and thoughts of the people who work here.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

<input name="Operation3" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
<input name="Operation4" type="submit" value="next" />
<input name="Operation5" type="submit" value="back" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

page3.php

//somecode//

Survey.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'classperson.php';


if($_POST['Operation1'])
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage2.php";
}

else if($_POST['Operation2'])
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
include "oopspage2.php";
}


elseif($_POST['Operation3'])

{
$_SESSION['effective'] = $effective;
$_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
$_SESSION['training'] = $training;
$_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
$_SESSION['treated'] = $treated;
$_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
$_SESSION['effort'] = $effort;
$_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey later http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/NextandBackButtons/page3.php";

}

elseif($_POST['Operation4'])
{
$_SESSION['effective'] = $effective;
$_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
$_SESSION['training'] = $training;
$_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
$_SESSION['treated'] = $treated;
$_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
$_SESSION['effort'] = $effort;
$_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];
include "oopspage3.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation5'])     /* THE PROBLEM LIES IN THIS CODE FOR BACK BUTTON*/
{
$location = $_POST['location'];
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="1.php" method="post"> /*oBVIOUSLY i WONT BE ALLOWED TO DECLARE <HTML> INSIDE PHP*/
<input type="submit" value="back"/>
</form> 
</body> 
}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
?>

could you please help me how to implement the back button . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using POST operations, which will make pretty much ALL browsers complain to the user about reposting previously submitted data. You cannot work around this unless you fundamentally change how your form works.

Comment: Hi Marc. Yes I know it would take lot more time if we use POST method but since I am very new to php this is all I know . Is there a way we can work around this ?Thanks

Comment: This is something related to the browsers and PHP has nothing to do. But you can do one thing. You can use tabs to have previous and next. Let me post an answer for that.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks a lot Praveen :) Will be waiting fo your post :)

Comment: @MarcB could you give me link for the tutorial where I can read upon it ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this i hope its work for you

Page1.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
//$session=session_id();
//$_SESSION['session']=$session;
//print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">
  Where do you work?<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="location" value="USA" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['location'])    == 'USA') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  In the United states<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="location" value="India" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['location']) == 'India') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Outside of the United states<br/>
  <input name="Operation1" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
  <input name="Operation2" type="submit" value="next" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page2.php

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">
  In my work group, we are actively involved in making our work processes more effective and efficient (simpler, faster, etc.) using ACE.<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effective'])    == 'Agree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Agree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agreenordisagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effective'])    == 'Agreenordisagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="disagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effective'])    == 'disagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Disagree<br/>
  I have received the training I need to understand and implement ACE in my work group.<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['training'])    == 'Agree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Agree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agreenordisagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['training'])    == 'Agreenordisagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="training" value="disagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['training'])    == 'disagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Disagree<br/>
  All employees at the company are treated fairly regardless of differences.<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['treated'])    == 'Agree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Agree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agreenordisagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['treated'])    == 'Agreenordisagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="disagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['treated'])    == 'disagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Disagree<br/>
  Sufficient effort is made to get the opinions and thoughts of the people who work here.<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effort'])    == 'Agree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Agree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agreenordisagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effort'])    == 'Agreenordisagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
  <Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="disagree" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['effort'])    == 'disagree') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>
  Disagree<br/>
  <input name="Operation3" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
  <input name="Operation4" type="submit" value="next" />
  <input name="Operation1" type="submit" value="back" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page3.php Or oopssurvey.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
//include 'classperson.php';

if(isset($_POST['Operation1']))
{
    if($_POST['Operation1'] == 'saveandresume'){
        $_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
        echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage2.php";
    }else if($_POST['Operation1'] == 'back') {
        include "page1.php";            
    }
}

else if(isset($_POST['Operation2'])){
    include "page2.php";
}


elseif(isset($_POST['Operation3'])){

$_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
$_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
$_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
$_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey later http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/NextandBackButtons/page3.php";
}

elseif(isset($_POST['Operation4']))
{
    if($_POST['Operation4'] == 'next'){
        echo "welcome to form3";    
        //include "oopspage3.php";
    }else{
    /*$_SESSION['effective'] = $effective;
    $_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
    $_SESSION['training'] = $training;
    $_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
    $_SESSION['treated'] = $treated;
    $_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
    $_SESSION['effort'] = $effort;
    $_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];*/   

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: as described by @query master, it is better to store the values in session and call them whenever and where ever you need it